# how to update custom MKAnnotationView after change to custom MKAnnotation data?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

Is there a way to update custom MKAnnotationView after change to custom MKAnnotation data?  Is this where observers come into play (haven't used these before).

Currently for example I am doing the following manually:

In my custom MKAnnotation after making changes to data:

```
let annView: GCCustomAnnotationView = self.mapView.viewForAnnotation(annotation) as! GCCustomAnnotationView
annView.updateText()
```

In my custom MKAnnotationView:

```
func updateText() {
    let gcAnnotation : GCAnnotation = self.annotation as! GCAnnotation
    calloutView.line1.text = gcAnnotation.locality
    calloutView.line2.text = gcAnnotation.sublocality
    calloutView.line3.text = gcAnnotation.name
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement KVO to observe changes in the annotation's data. That is the mechanism that is used by the `MKAnnotationView` class to observe changes in the `coordinate` property of `MKAnnotation`. Standard Swift doesn't use KVO, it is more of a ObjectiveC leftover thing and a bit of a hassle to implement in [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_8). A simple solution I used is to call `setNeedsDisplay` on the custom annotation view when the annotation's data has changed. This causes `drawRect` to be called. Within your implementation of `drawRect` you can then poll the annotation's data (as you do in your code snippet) to change the appearance of the view.

So long story short, when your data changes:

```
annView.setNeedsDisplay()
```

is all you need in your case.

Then within your `drawRect` implementation of your subclassed `MKAnnotationView` instance you call your `updateText` function:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    updateText()
    // etc.
}
```